# Node.js: global error handler not working

Tags: node.js, error-handling, global

I am trying to create a global route to handle the error pages like 404, 500, etc.

src/index.js

```js
const App = express();

import Accounts from './application/accounts/routes.js';
import AccountTypes from './application/account-types/routes.js';
...

App.use('/accounts', Accounts);
App.use('/account-types', AccountTypes);
...

App.use((error, req, res, next) => {
    console.error(error.stack);

    res.status(500).json(error.message)
});

App.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log(`Node is listing on ${PORT}`);
});
```

However, it only works if I am creating the error handler method in each route file.

application/accounts/routes.js and application/account-types/routes.js

```js
const Router = express.Router();

Router.all('*', (req, res) => res.status(400).send({
    'error': 'Invalid route or missing required parameter(s)',
}));
```

What is it that I am doing wrong..?

Comment: `App.all('*', (req, res) => ....)`?

Comment: Tried, but did not work..